# R pattern matching multiple combinations of rows in columns for replacement?

Tags: r, string, gsub

I'm trying to figure out how to identify instances of any strings from one column of a dataframe on another column in that same dataframe in order to replace. In this case I have forum postings I've pulled in which people reference other users by name and I want to get rid of those names for analyses otherwise they will count as high quantity words. Below is the dput for this data frame:

```
structure(list(uber_name = structure(c(9L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 
3L, 9L, 11L), .Label = c("aluber1968", "bigdreamslittlemoney", 
"FuberNYC", "JamesM", "jonnyplastic", "JustDre", "KING D", "klimarov", 
"NycGirl705", "shumacker", "spike69", "theitalian", "Uberman8263", 
"Ez2dj", "Manhmptn", "NYCDriver", "staytune", "UBS", "Ubured", 
"Jme10", "Lennyyellowcab", "Mir", "eagle88", "Ibuys4730", "NoUsername", 
"BathoTrask", "Douglas", "LGC", "Jakeinny098", "Rustyshackelford", 
"shabbyroch", "ubershiza", "drbrkln", "elys123", "bossdriver", 
"HerbyHerb", "Jim1985", "Malik38", "STIDRIVER", "vxlon7", "Waqar", 
"tohunt4me", "DogPound", "SuliB", "AlBrklyn", "John Cunningham", 
"MReeves", "PinkFoot", "alextheboss", "luisannalui", "censoredbytheFCC", 
"KONY", "cieru", "Jorlev", "Smooth954", "marcusguber", "nyc321", 
"Tony from New Jersey", "Vanstaal", "Bkrah", "brunoamat2", "gebbels6", 
"Kevin7889", "uanic", "Uber OG", "UberKilledMyMarriage", "ya mon its me", 
"HunkAWestchester", "Mr Affinito", "ninja warrior", "NoNonsense", 
"notacabdriver", "Notauberhater", "TwoFiddyMile", "bilyvh", "cybertec69", 
"JohnnyBlanco", "SOBE", "ubernyc"), class = "factor"), uber_write = c("I see people post about getting a w", 
"you have 2 choices either you drive", "More than a year ago I didnt drive ", 
"yeah i stopped driving for them for", "Ive been getting some promotions la", 
"FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", "shumacker saidAnd You feel importan", 
"FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", "They start coming after few months "
), uber_date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("Jan 19, 2017", "Mar 30, 2017", "Jan 23, 2017", 
"Jan 12, 2017", "Jan 9, 2017", "Jan 1, 2017", "Dec 31, 2016", 
"Nov 26, 2016", "Nov 3, 2016", "Dec 22, 2016", "Dec 13, 2016", 
"Dec 2, 2016", "Nov 15, 2016", "Oct 31, 2016", "Oct 20, 2016", 
"Mar 14, 2017", "Sep 1, 2016", "Jul 26, 2016", "Mar 1, 2017", 
"Feb 25, 2017", "Sep 8, 2016", "Sep 9, 2016", "Apr 21, 2015"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("uber_name", 
"uber_write", "uber_date"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000220788>)
```

I've used gsub before but I can't figure out how to apply it to this instance. I want to take any names in the "uber_names" column and removes these users from any of the "uber_writes" that is the postings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a vector `uber_names` of all user names in your data.table (`dt`) and then generate a regular expression `(name1|name2|name3)` to replace all matching user names with `""`, like:

```
library(data.table)
uber_names <- dt$uber_name
dt[, uber_write_filtered := gsub(
    pattern = paste0("(", paste(uber_names, collapse = "|"), ")"),
    replacement = "", uber_write)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to recreate your data frame but here's one that's close:

```
data <- 
structure(list(uber_name = c("aluber1968", "bigdreamslittlemoney", 
"FuberNYC", "JamesM", "jonnyplastic", "JustDre", "KING D", "klimarov", 
"NycGirl705", "shumacker", "spike69", "theitalian", "Uberman8263", 
"Ez2dj", "Manhmptn", "NYCDriver", "staytune", "UBS", "Ubured", 
"Jme10", "Lennyyellowcab", "Mir", "eagle88", "Ibuys4730", "NoUsername", 
"BathoTrask", "Douglas", "LGC", "Jakeinny098", "Rustyshackelford", 
"shabbyroch", "ubershiza", "drbrkln", "elys123", "bossdriver", 
"HerbyHerb", "Jim1985", "Malik38", "STIDRIVER", "vxlon7", "Waqar", 
"tohunt4me", "DogPound", "SuliB", "AlBrklyn", "John Cunningham", 
"MReeves", "PinkFoot", "alextheboss", "luisannalui", "censoredbytheFCC", 
"KONY", "cieru", "Jorlev", "Smooth954", "marcusguber", "nyc321", 
"Tony from New Jersey", "Vanstaal", "Bkrah", "brunoamat2", "gebbels6", 
"Kevin7889", "uanic", "Uber OG", "UberKilledMyMarriage", "ya mon its me", 
"HunkAWestchester", "Mr Affinito", "ninja warrior", "NoNonsense", 
"notacabdriver", "Notauberhater", "TwoFiddyMile", "bilyvh", "cybertec69", 
"JohnnyBlanco", "SOBE", "ubernyc"), uber_write = c("I see people post about getting a w", 
"you have 2 choices either you drive", "More than a year ago I didnt drive ", 
"yeah i stopped driving for them for", "Ive been getting some promotions la", 
"FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", "shumacker saidAnd You feel importan", 
"FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", "They start coming after few months ", 
"I see people post about getting a w", "you have 2 choices either you drive", 
"More than a year ago I didnt drive ", "yeah i stopped driving for them for", 
"Ive been getting some promotions la", "FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", 
"shumacker saidAnd You feel importan", "FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", 
"They start coming after few months ", "I see people post about getting a w", 
"you have 2 choices either you drive", "More than a year ago I didnt drive ", 
"yeah i stopped driving for them for", "Ive been getting some promotions la", 
"FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", "shumacker saidAnd You feel importan", 
"FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", "They start coming after few months ", 
"I see people post about getting a w", "you have 2 choices either you drive", 
"More than a year ago I didnt drive ", "yeah i stopped driving for them for", 
"Ive been getting some promotions la", "FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", 
"shumacker saidAnd You feel importan", "FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", 
"They start coming after few months ", "I see people post about getting a w", 
"you have 2 choices either you drive", "More than a year ago I didnt drive ", 
"yeah i stopped driving for them for", "Ive been getting some promotions la", 
"FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", "shumacker saidAnd You feel importan", 
"FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", "They start coming after few months ", 
"I see people post about getting a w", "you have 2 choices either you drive", 
"More than a year ago I didnt drive ", "yeah i stopped driving for them for", 
"Ive been getting some promotions la", "FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", 
"shumacker saidAnd You feel importan", "FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", 
"They start coming after few months ", "I see people post about getting a w", 
"you have 2 choices either you drive", "More than a year ago I didnt drive ", 
"yeah i stopped driving for them for", "Ive been getting some promotions la", 
"FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", "shumacker saidAnd You feel importan", 
"FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", "They start coming after few months ", 
"I see people post about getting a w", "you have 2 choices either you drive", 
"More than a year ago I didnt drive ", "yeah i stopped driving for them for", 
"Ive been getting some promotions la", "FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", 
"shumacker saidAnd You feel importan", "FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", 
"They start coming after few months ", "I see people post about getting a w", 
"you have 2 choices either you drive", "More than a year ago I didnt drive ", 
"yeah i stopped driving for them for", "Ive been getting some promotions la", 
"FuberNYC saidIve been getting some ", "shumacker saidAnd You feel importan"
)), .Names = c("uber_name", "uber_write"), row.names = c(NA, 
-79L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here's an answer:

```
paste0(data$uber_name, collapse = "|") -> dont_want
data$uber_write2 <- gsub(pattern = dont_want, "", data$uber_write)
```